# How is it shown that $l^p\subset l^q$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I have the following problem in my textbook which the answer to is not quite clear. It's not clear how it proves the fact that $l^p\subset l^q$.

So here's the problem:

Show that if $1\leq p\leq q\leq \infty$ then $l^p\subset l^q$ and $$||x||_{l^q}\leq ||x||_{l^p}$$ for every $x\in l^p$.

The full answer:

Suppose that $x\in l^p$ with $||x||_{l^p}=1$, and so in particular $|x_j|\leq 1$ for every $j$. If $q=\infty$ then it is immediate that $||x||_{l^{\infty}}\leq 1$.

If $q< \infty$ then, since $q\geq p$, it follow that $|x_j|^q\leq |x_j|^p$. Therefore

$$||x||_{l^q}^q=\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j|^q\leq \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j|^p=1$$

i.e $||x||_{l^q}\leq 1$

Given a general non-zero $x\in l^p$, consider $y=x/||x||_{l^p}$; then $$||y||_{l^q}=\biggl|\biggl|\frac{x}{||x||_{l^p}}\biggr|\biggr|_{l^q}=\frac{||x||_{l^q}}{||x||_{l^p}}\leq 1$$

and so $||x||_{l^q}\leq ||x||_{l^p}$

I understand everything from this proof, but I don't understand how is $l^p\subset l^q$? Also, what does this exactly mean for a sequence space to be a subset of a sequence space? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence $x$ belongs to $\ell^p$ if its $p$-norm is finite. Saying $\ell^p\subset \ell^q$ means you have to show every element of $\ell^p$ is also an element of $\ell^q$, or what amounts to the same thing "if the $p$-norm of a sequence is finite then the $q$-norm is also finite". Based on the inequality you established, that is precisely the conclusion you can draw (clearly, if the RHS of an inequality is finite, then the LHS is finite).